# Is this a correct community to ask ontology related questions?

Tags: support

I have a term regarding knowledge representation in information systems and I'd like to know where to place my questions regarding ontology in business processes.

Comment: Depends. Do you want to ask about the relation of the ontology and the reality of business processes, or about properties of formal representations of these ontologies?